Package "@angular-builders/custom-webpack" was found but does not support schematics in angular 17
My angular json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "new_project_mc": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/new_project_mc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "new_project_mc:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "new_project_mc:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "new_project_mc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

My Package JSON
{
  "name": "new-project-mc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^18.0.4",
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "node-gyp-build-optional-packages": "^5.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

I was tried to run my project but it through an error

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(customWebpackConfig).

MY Angular CLI INFO


try to change all @angular-builders to @angular-devkit

it's still not working and through
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(customWebpackConfig).

@Tentely
I want to load custom web pack configuration.

I have exactly the same problem. When adding the custom-webpack to Angular, it didn't bother updating the schema.json, so now the angular.json doesn't validate against the schema.
My hunch is that if you add "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser" to "The builder used for this package" and add a matching "builder" and a matching "... target" schema definition, then it'll validate.
However, I'm not entirely sure what the schema is supposed to be containing and I'm having a great deal of difficulty trying to find an example schema.json that supports custom-webpack.

could you please share the validate schema package sample ?
